# linq to sql query optimization suggestions needed

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

firstly i wrote this query

```
var lst = (from mediaref in MediaRefs
               join media in Medias 
               on mediaref.Int_MediaId equals media.Int_MediaId
               join mediatype in MediaTypes
               on media.Int_MediaTypeId equals mediatype.Int_MediaTypeId
               where mediatype.Int_MediaTypeId_FK == 1 
                   && mediaref.Bit_IsActive == true
                   && media.Int_OrganizationId == 2
                   && media.Int_PostStatusId != 3 
                   && mediaref.Int_MediaRefId == mediaref.Media.
               MediaRefs.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Int_MediaId == media.Int_MediaId 
               && m.Bit_IsActive == true &&
               (m.Nvcr_MediaTitle != null 
               && m.Nvcr_MediaTitle != "")).Int_MediaRefId
               orderby media.Int_MediaId descending

               select new MediaViewModel {
                  MediaId = media.Int_MediaId,
                  Mediatitle = mediaref.Nvcr_MediaTitle ,
                  Mediapath = mediaref.Vcr_MediaPath,
                  Slug = mediaref.Vcr_Slug,
                  Active = mediaref.Bit_IsActive
                });
```

then changed to this

```
var lst = (from mediaref in MediaRefs
               join media in Medias 
               on mediaref.Int_MediaId equals media.Int_MediaId
               join mediatype in MediaTypes on
               media.Int_MediaTypeId equals mediatype.Int_MediaTypeId
               where mediatype.Int_MediaTypeId_FK == 1 
                     && mediaref.Bit_IsActive == true
                     && media.Int_OrganizationId == 2 
                     && media.Int_PostStatusId != 3 
                     && mediaref.Nvcr_MediaTitle != ""                         
               group new {mediaref, Medias, MediaTypes} by new {
                     media.Int_MediaId,                         
                     mediaref.Vcr_MediaPath,
                     mediaref.Vcr_Slug,
                     mediaref.Bit_IsActive                       
                }  into g
                      orderby  g.Key.Int_MediaId descending

                select new MediaViewModel {
                  MediaId = Convert.ToInt64(g.Key.Int_MediaId),
                  Mediatitle = g.Min(p => p.mediaref.Nvcr_MediaTitle) == "" ? 
                         g.Max(p => p.mediaref.Nvcr_MediaTitle) : 
                         g.Min(p => p.mediaref.Nvcr_MediaTitle),
                  Mediapath = g.Key.Vcr_MediaPath,
                  Slug = g.Key.Vcr_Slug,
                  Active = g.Key.Bit_IsActive
                });
```

Can this query be written in somewhat more efficient way?.  the problem is that I want to join `media` with the first row of `mediaref` which always will bring 3 rows for each `media`. any suggestions. in this first query I have used `FirstOrDefault` and in second query I have used `group by`.

Comment: Please format your code nicely so it compares easily. Make it non-scrolling and indicate the differences. Better questions = better answers.

Comment: OK, much better! Another question: are there a navigation properties like `Media.MediaRefs` (1-n) and `Media.MediaType` (n-1)? You would not have to join manually.

Comment: yes there are navigation properties

Comment: should i rely more on navigation properties?

Answer (score 0):

I think I would go for the first version of your query but with some modifications. A bit like this (I'm not going to write down the whole lot):

```
from m in Medias
where m.MediaType.Int_MediaTypeId_FK == 1
let firstmediaref = m.MediaRefs
                     .FirstOrDefault(ref => ref.Bit_IsActive 
                           && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ref.Nvcr_MediaTitle))
```

and build your `MediaViewModel` with `m` and `firstmediaref`.